# Is bower package manager dying?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, jspm

I Recently heard that [bower](http://bower.io/) package manager is dying.
I didn't found any official statement from the bower team.

1. is there any official statement from the bower team that I can read about it?
2. what are the good alternative for package manager? (npm, jspm, other options)
3. should I start to use alternative package manager?

Comment: http://bower.io/blog/2015/bower-alive-looking-contributors/, http://bower.io/blog/2015/bower-is-growing-join-us/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question in its current form. It's primarily asking "what is the current status of Bower?" Closing it because it has a subquestion about alternatives is being pedantic.

Comment: To answer the question (because it is relevant) - yes, Bower is dying, and has been for a while now. If things don't change I would not be surprised to see a deprecation announcement from what's left of the team/community within the next year. NPM is rapidly moving towards becoming the de-facto package manager for browser projects, and many major projects default to it.